# Find the expected value of A = 3Y^2

Tags: statistics

I'm having a hard time understanding this question.

Let Y be a Normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\delta$. Find the expected value of $A = 3{Y}^2$.

Could someone please explain what is $A = 3{Y}^2$ and how it relates to the question? Isn't the mean equal to the expected value? Thank you!

I'm studying CDF and PDF right now in the course.

Comment: Yes, the mean is the expected value. And $E(A)=E(3Y^2)=3E(Y^2)$. Now can you find $E(Y^2)$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Okay so I have to take the derivative to get $\mu$ and $\delta$, right? But how do I do that if there's no equation to take the derivative from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $E(A)=E(3Y^2)=3E(Y^2)$.  It remains to find $E(Y^2)$.

I expect you are familiar with the formula
$$\text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2.\tag{1}$$
The standard deviation of $Y$ is $\delta$, so $\text{Var}(Y)=\delta^2$. And $E(Y)=\mu$, so $(E(Y))^2=\mu^2$. It now follows that $E(Y^2)=\delta^2+\mu^2$, and now we are almost finished.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I was really confused on what the question was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If $Y$ is a random variable, then $Y^2$ is a random variable, and so is $3Y^2$. We could imagine finding the mean of $Y^2$ by first finding the *density function* of $Y^2$, and then using the usual formula for mean. Or else we could calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 f(y)\,dy$, where $f(y)$ is the density function of $Y$, which you probably know. Both methods, specially the first, are quite painful. The method given in the answer is quick.